# ABCpdf - How to implement CSS using AddHtml?

Tags: html, css, .net, abcpdf

```
for (int i = 1; i <= theCount; i++)
{
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(footerHtml))
          {
              theDoc.PageNumber = i;
              theDoc.AddText("Page " + i + " of " + theCount);
              //theDoc.AddHtml("My-html-code-with-internal-css-was-here")
          }

}
```

I want to add footer with the above logic incrementing the number of pages in .NET using ABCpdf.
My **HTML doc** displays the same CSS that I'm using in AddHtml. Still not getting the CSS with the text in **PDF**. It displays "Page 1 of 3" in classic HTML formatting.

Comment: What version of ABCpdf are you using?

Comment: Why not build html with the Page 1 of 3 in it and use .AddHtml()?